# How do I change the content of one XML tag for successive webAPI calls?

Tags: python, xml, asp.net-web-api, beautifulsoup, ebay-api

I currently am working with eBay API and Python's requests package. Specifically, I have a list of ItemID's (about 10,000 or so) that I got from eBay's Finding API and now I want to use those IDs with the TradingAPI to get the item images. 
For example, this would be the body of my request.

```
xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><GetItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Version>1085</Version>
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>YourTokenhere</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
  <MessageID>XML call: OAuth Token in trading</MessageID>
   <DetailLevel>ItemReturnAttributes</DetailLevel>
  <ItemID>254140401476</ItemID><OutputSelector>Item.PictureDetails.PictureURL</OutputSelector>
  <IncludeItemSpecifics>false</IncludeItemSpecifics>
</GetItemRequest>"""
```

So my question is: 
What is the most efficient way/best practice to change the value of ItemID with each API call?

Some problems I have faced:

1. I can use BeautifulSoup to easily change the value, but then the xml is now a BeautifulSoup object. So far I have not found a way in BeautifulSoup to convert back to xml. I have tried using encode("utf-8") but this puts newlines into the xml.
2. In the Python requests module documentation, they say that you can directly submit a dict, which would make the value easier to change. But I'm not sure how to convert the XML to dict, for example the 
   `<GetItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">` tag. Also I'm not sure eBay API will even accept this.
3. I have tried to use xmltodict as well, but I haven't had success with this which makes me think eBay API will not accept this format of ordered dictionary either.
4. My overarching problem with converting XML to a tree using ElementTree (haven't tried this yet but that would be my next step) or BeautifulSoup  and then trying to convert back again is just that it seems really inefficient.

I appreciate any help or advice! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a list of item ids, like:

```
item_ids = [254140401476,111140406666] #etc.
```

and you want the element `<ItemID>` in your xml to be populated in turn with each if so, this can be done with f-strings:

```
 for id in item_ids:
    print(f"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><GetItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Version>1085</Version>
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>YourTokenhere</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
  <MessageID>XML call: OAuth Token in trading</MessageID>
   <DetailLevel>ItemReturnAttributes</DetailLevel>
  <ItemID>{id}</ItemID><OutputSelector>Item.PictureDetails.PictureURL</OutputSelector>
  <IncludeItemSpecifics>false</IncludeItemSpecifics>
</GetItemRequest>""")
```

Note that the `<ItemID>` element now contains the variable `<ItemID>{id}</ItemID>` instead of a hardwired item id.

Comment: thank you one million!!! That worked like a charm. I didn’t even know that f string existed so you really saved me :’)